# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImageRenderer.encodeEnd(GraphicImageRenderer.java:43)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, nullpointerexception, inputstream, graphicimage

I have an `InputStream` received from an API request to show in a `p:graphicImage` like that

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{bean.selectedItem.dashboardImage}" />
```

selectedItem is an HashMap and I checked the dashboardImage field is not null,
however the following exception is throwed:

```
mar 29, 2021 6:39:21 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/modelList.xhtml]
java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter url is null
    at org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImageRenderer.encodeEnd(GraphicImageRenderer.java:43)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at it.bisy.lac.webClient.webapp.filter.MessageFilter.doFilter(MessageFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at it.bisy.lac.webClient.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter url is null
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.encodeResourceURL(ExternalContextImpl.java:616)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.encodeResourceURL(ExternalContextWrapper.java:145)
    at org.primefaces.util.DynamicContentSrcBuilder.build(DynamicContentSrcBuilder.java:116)
    at org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImageRenderer.getImageSrc(GraphicImageRenderer.java:75)
    at org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImageRenderer.encodeEnd(GraphicImageRenderer.java:41)
    ... 120 more
```

I tried to put in dashboardImage a `byte[]` but the exception continues to persist

how can I fix it?

My PrimeFaces version is 6.1

Comment: You didn't mention your version of PrimeFaces. Also did you check out this example in the documentation? https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/graphicimage?id=getting-started-with-graphicimage

Comment: I upgraded the primefaces version to 8.0 and now I solve it. Thank you very much

Comment: You should post your answer so you can mark your own question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by updating the version of primefaces to 8.0